# Run selenium scripts in Internet Explorer

Tags: selenium-rc

I am currently using Selenium RC to run my scripts in FF in windows. Could you tell me how to run the scripts in IE as well?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear, but assuming you mean you are using the Selenium IDE Firefox plugin to create your tests, you will find [this blog post helpful](http://www.jadeliquid.com/blogs/2011/running-selenium-tests-from-the-command-line.php).

- You need java installed.
- If you're on Windows you probably need to run the command as administrator.

Then run the following command as administrator

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.0b3.jar -htmlSuite "*iexplore" 
   "http://www.google.com" "TestSuite.html" 
   "results.html" -port 4445
```

where the parameter `"*iexplore"` specifies to use InternetExplorer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using  `*firefox or *chrome` in your script , use `*iexplore or *iexploreproxy`